# How to break the texts(of a Text file) to next line using python or Shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a text file, file contains logs,the problem is all logs are in single line, I have to break the logs in separate lines by using  python or shell script.

I am not getting any way how to do it.

Sample file contents:

```
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs           2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER                                   itzpiascs           2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs
```

Comment: Please share expected output

Comment: What should one line look like? Where would you split the lines?

Comment: expected output -  2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs  
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER                                   itzpiascs  
2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs

Comment: @Nikhil.J. move the output to your question with formatting

Comment: New line should be start from 2AUK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> New line should be start from 2AUK  – Nikhil.J

***Python*** solution (tested on Python 3.5):

```
import re
with open('log.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = re.sub(r'(?<!^)2AUK', '\n2AUK', re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', f.read().strip()))
    print(contents)
```

---

Alternative ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/ /g; s/\<2AUK/\n&/g' file
```

The output:

```
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs 
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER itzpiascs 
2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs
```

---

- `s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/ /g` - suppressing excessive spaces
- `s/\<2AUK/\n&/g` - prepend newline to each `2AUK` to obtain separate lines

Comment: by using sed  what, if there are two more keyword instead of "itzpiascs" like "itzrollat" or " itxrload" ?

Comment: @Nikhil.J, you have said: *New line should be start from 2AUK* and nothing about "itzpiascs"

Comment: yeah got it! I was thinking only in one way, from ending of file.Thanks Allot!

Comment: i have one more file in which log start with 2AU and 2BU. can i give or condition ?

Comment: @Nikhil.J, yes, you can

Comment: where should i give?

Comment: for ex. in my python approach: `... r'(?<!^)(2AUK|2BU)', '\n\\1' ...`

Comment: how to do in sed?

Comment: @Nikhil.J, `s/\<\(2AUK\|2BU\)/\n\1/g`

Answer (score 2):

If I get it correctly, you want a file with 4 columns of data. With the use of `awk`, the solution will look like this:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<NF/4; i++) print $(i*4+1)" "$(i*4+2)" "$(i*4+3)" "$(i*4+4)}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs
```

Comment: Change `file` to  your file name. Add space and `>newfile` to print output to a file `newfile`.

Comment: This will work but you might consider adding a little explanation to your answer.

Comment: The problem is SAP server is writing the logs in a single line, It is appending the logs in same line. So i have to break the each logs to next  line.

Comment: @Nikhil.J so either your data is different, or you enter the command incorrectly.

Comment: @Nikhil.J based on the information you provided, this answer does precisely what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the re (regular expression) library in python to accomplish this. This would replace any whitespace in the text with a new line character.

```python
import re
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    print(re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', f.read()))
```

If you wanted to do more complicated manipulation you could use `re.split` to get a list of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

From your data, it appears that your individual log entries end with `itzpiascs`, so just break on that:

```
sed -i -r $'s/itzpiascs\\s+/itzpiascs\\\n/g' your_file.log
```

Your file will turn into:

```
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER                                   itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1                     SAPMSSY1                                3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI                                          itzpiascs
```

You can remove `-i` argument not to change the file, or put something like `-i.bak` instead to create a backup of the original before changing it.

**edit**: If you want to remove the excessive whitespace, you can just chain another replacement:

```
sed -i -r $'s/\\s+/ /g; s/itzpiascs\\s+/itzpiascs\\\n/g' your_file.log
```

Turning your file to:

```
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000006002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001SYSU&&SYSTEM_RESET_RFC_SERVER itzpiascs
2AUK20170407000007002840700014DeitzpiascECCSERVICE1 SAPMSSY1 3001ZRFC_ICICI&&ZRFC_ICICI itzpiascs
```

Comment: what, if there are two more keyword instead of "itzpiascs" like "itzrollat" or " itxrload" ?

Comment: Just use the last one's value instead of `itzpiascs` in the pattern to break on it...